# Input is always `valid` in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a react component like so

```
export const SearchBar = ({
  searchInput,
  updateSearchKeyword,
}: SearchBarProps) => {
  const dummy = "";
  return (
    <div className={`${styles.container} `}>
      <input
        className={`${styles["search-bar"]} `}
        type={"text"}
        value={dummy}
        title="search"
        placeholder="Search..."
        onChange={(e) => updateSearchKeyword(e.target.value)}
      />      
    </div>
  );
};
```

And I want to make come CSS changes when the Input filed has text in it. So, my CSS is like below

```
.search-bar:valid {
  color: red;
}
```

However, the color is always red! In other words, in put is always 'valid'

I tried

```
.search-bar[type="text"]:valid {
  color: red;
}
```

and even  adding a `pattern` in the component. It is not working how do I fix this?

PS: I am using `modules.css`, hence the class names are a bit strange but they are working as expected for other properties.

Comment: Well it is valid...? Why do you think it should be invalid?

Comment: Because it is an empty string. If I am using the input form for search using `useState`, I initialize it with an empty string.

Comment: An empty input field is not invalid unless the field is marked `required` which that input isn't.

Comment: Thank you! That works. I did not know that. If you can put that as answer, I will up-vote & accept it.

Answer (score -1):

you only declare

```
className={`${styles["search-bar"]} `}
```

you never update this, so yes, are gona be always red.

then, another mistake when you put:

```
const dummy = "";
value={dummy}
```

You will be not able to change the value of this input. You have to use like this:

```
const [dummy, setDummy] = useState('')
```

and then on the input:

```
value={dummy}
onChange={(e)=>setDummy(e.target.value)}
```

but this not solves you problem, but you can:

```
onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e.target.value)}
```

and just declare this:

```
const handleChange = (value) => {

setDummy(value)

if (dummy !== '') {
// here change the style of ur input (the color)
}
```

}

###################

to change the style u can:

1. document.getelemntbyId... bla bla bla (booooring)

or BETTER: declare the style on a state like this:

```
const [myStyle, setMyStyle] = useState(`${styles["search-bar"]}`)
```

and then when u want to change ur style just actualize using

```
setMyStyle(`${styles["search-bar-blue"]}`)
```

Then for the validation you need to declare a css pattern to check if true or false:

```
<input pattern="[a-z]+" type.../>
```

On the example is gona validate true ONLY if input are ONLY lowercase letters

Comment: I actually am using `useState` with an empty string as the starting value & doing all that you have suggested. My question is with respect to why an empty string is `valid`

Comment: Yes, sorry, forget this:

Since you don't declare a "pattern" your validation are gona be true ALWAYS.

to test it you can try to add this on your input: 

pattern="[a-z]+"

this is gona validate as a true ONLY with lower case letters, and is gona swap to false if you type any capital letter. 

You need to check this info:

1) css pattern
2) RegExp